# How to normalize TF*IDF or counts in scikit-learn?

Tags: scikit-learn, nlp, tf-idf, countvectorizer

I want to check the cosine similarity of two documents having varying length (say one is a one or two liner while other is of 100-200 lines).

I need a way to normalize tfidf or count vectorizer in scikit-learn for this.

Comment: Do you need to use cosine similarity? Or open to any other attempts?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Tiago Duque I need cosine similarity

Comment: @dmh cosine similarity using CountVecorizer, TfIdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TfidfVectorizer has an attribute `norm` (see [the docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html)) that deals with this issue. Try, for example, something like this:

```py
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(analyzer='word', stop_words='english', norm='l2')
```

This will normalise the vectors to account for differences in document lengths.